# Prometheus monitoring error "expected value after metric, got \"MNAME\"" for target endpoint

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

I setup prometheus on my machine and tested metrics for the default endpoint on which prometheus runs i.e localhost:9090.It worked fine.Now after changing the target to an endpoint of a server running locally,I am getting error and thus not able to get any metrics for the endpoint.

New endpoint - http://0.0.0.0:8090/health

Error Message:

level=warn ts=2019-10-16T07:12:28.713Z caller=scrape.go:930 component="scrape manager" scrape_pool=prometheus target=http://0.0.0.0:8090/health msg="append failed" err="expected value after metric, got \"MNAME\""

Attaching a screenshot of the prometheus.yml file to verify the configurations.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your `/health` endpoint produces Prometheus metrics? Prometheus expects to scrape something that looks like this:

```
# HELP alertmanager_alerts How many alerts by state.
# TYPE alertmanager_alerts gauge
alertmanager_alerts{state="active"} 7
alertmanager_alerts{state="suppressed"} 0
# HELP alertmanager_alerts_invalid_total The total number of received alerts that were invalid.
# TYPE alertmanager_alerts_invalid_total counter
alertmanager_alerts_invalid_total{version="v1"} 0
alertmanager_alerts_invalid_total{version="v2"} 0
```

Is that similar to what you see if you open `http://host:8090/health` in your browser? Based on the error message you're seeing, I seriously doubt it.