# Python http server Prometheus error: expected timestamp or new record, got "MNAME"

Tags: python, prometheus

Trying to write an endpoint with 2 metrics from a python http server which does not work. For whatever reason, the prometheus parser does not know how to parse html like a br linebreak in between, which is really bad..

If I use a single metric like line 1 only, it works.

I also tried \n, but that works also only for the first metric. Since there will be no linebreak in the html post, the second metric is not recognized as metric??!

```
self.wfile.write(bytes(f'sensor1{{type="mylabel1"}} 77', "utf-8"))
self.wfile.write(bytes(f' <br>', "utf-8"))
self.wfile.write(bytes(f'sensor2{{type="mylabel2"}} 78', "utf-8"))
```

My Html Page post looks like in this answer
[Prometheus monitoring error "expected value after metric, got \"MNAME\"" for target endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58408076/prometheus-monitoring-error-expected-value-after-metric-got-mname-for-tar)

```
sensor1{type="mylabel1"} 77
sensor2{type="mylabel2"} 78
```

Any idea what kind of linebreak is expected by the parser? Code is python.

Comment: Try `encode()` with `\n` included in the string? ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode

Comment: No, already tried before will lead to no linebreak. But that is usual for html I suppose. self.wfile.write('\n').encode("utf-8"))

Comment: `Somehow the html linebreak br is not allowed.` Its not allowed because Prometheus does not scrape HTML. `My Html Page post looks like in this answer` _It shouldn't be a HTML page._

Comment: Yeah, thats the problem prometheus is too stupid. I am over it now. Tried so many things. Switchin to influx DB